# Firebase: Cloud Functions, How to Cache a Firestore Document Snapshot

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that I [call directly from my app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). This cloud function fetches a collection of Firestore documents, iterating over each, then returns a result.

My question is, would it be best to keep the result of that fetch/get in memory (on the node server), refreshed with `.onSnapshot`? It seems this would improve performance as my cloud function would not have to wait for the Firestore response (it would already have the collection in memory). How would I do this? Simple as populating a global variable? How to do `.onSnaphot` realtime listener with cloud functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it might depend how large these snapshots are and how many of them may be cached ...

because, it is a `RAM` disk and without house-keeping it might only work for a limited time.

> **Always delete temporary files**
>
> Local disk storage in the temporary directory is an in-memory file-system. Files that you write consume memory available to your function, and sometimes persist between invocations. Failing to explicitly delete these files may eventually lead to an out-of-memory error and a subsequent cold start.

Source: [Cloud Functions - Tips & Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips).

It does not tell there, what exactly the hard-limit would be - and caching elsewhere might not improve access time that much. [it says](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) `2048mb` per function, per default - while one can raise the quotas with [IAM & admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&usage=ALL). it all depends, if the quota per function can be raised far enough to handle the cache.

here's an example for the `.onShapshot()` event:

```
// for a single document:
var doc = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

// this also works for multiple documents:
// var docs = db.collection('cities').where('state', '==', 'CA');

var observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
 console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});

// unsubscribe, to stop listening for changes:
var unsub = db.collection('cities').onSnapshot(() => {});
unsub();
```

Source: [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

[Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function) might be another option.